# Parallel foreach memory leak with bitmaps

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, parallel.foreach

I want to select multiple ( in my case 77 ) images and convert them into other size and format.
I made a Ilist (string) listaslika that contains list of names of images from folder. tbSelect is a textbox that contains folder path where the images are from and tbSave contains a folder where images will be saved.
Now i want to resize all of them, even though i dispose everything, i have memory leaks, any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int W = Convert.ToInt32(txtW.Text);
        int H = Convert.ToInt32(txtH.Text);
        Parallel.ForEach(listaslika, slika =>
       {
           Bitmap bpm = new Bitmap(W, H);
           Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(bpm);
           img = Image.FromFile(tbSelect.Text + "\\" + slika);
           graphic.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, W, H);
           graphic.Dispose();
           img = bpm;
           ((Button)sender).Enabled = false;
           string select = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(slika);
           img.Save(tbSave.Text + "\\" + select + exten[GetSelecetedIndex()]);
           bpm.Dispose();
           img.Dispose();
       });
```

Comment: You did not dispose the image instance created with Image.FromFile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect that to look something more like:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int W = Convert.ToInt32(txtW.Text);
    int H = Convert.ToInt32(txtH.Text);
    Parallel.ForEach(listaslika, slika =>
    {
        using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(W, H))
        {
            using (Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(tbSelect.Text + "\\" + slika, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
                {
                    using (Image img = Image.FromStream(fs))
                    {
                        graphic.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, W, H);
                    }
                }
            }

            string select = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(slika);
            bmp.Save(tbSave.Text + "\\" + select + exten[GetSelecetedIndex()]);
        }               
    });
}
```

Comment: You can optionally remove the curly brackets for the second and third using block for better reading

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
But after ceratin time memory usage drops to zero. When using both regular foreach and parallel.forach with maxdegreeofparallelism=1 it is going ok. Any ideas what i should do in order to make parallel.foreach go well? @SirRufo

Comment: It is not only memory usage but also the file will be locked until the image instance is disposed or garbage collected

Comment: @JulianCosta You have more problems than memory leaks? Why is that not in your question? How SO works: You ask a question and we answer **that** question. You can edit the question to clarify it but do not extend the question or ask something completely different. In that case ask a new question